# Why is Meteor.userId() reactive? Does it have to be?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am new to Meteor, and am trying to wrap my head around some of the concepts.

Some of the Account stuff doesn't quite make sense to me -- like why do I want the user ID of the logged in user to be reactive?  It seems like that is not something likely to change too often, and can get annoying when (at least in React) `this.currentUser.profile.name` is temporarily undefined.

Are there advantages to having the user account reactive?  Does it have to be?

Comment: It's useful for detecting when a person is logged in or not. That way logged out users don't have access to things they shouldn't. On the server, to check who a user is you should use `this.userId`

Comment: @Rager thanks -- I get the idea of why I want to know if someone is logged in, but not why it needs to be a reactive resource.  It just seems like a lot of overhead in figuring out who a person is -- though I assume I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important to redirect user reactively to public (ex: login) or private (ex: dashboard) pages depending on the value of `Meteor.userId()`.

Comment: Thanks -- but assuming that theres a redirect login flow, I dont see how the logged in state takes anyone by surprise.  And determining WHO was signed in shouldnt change for as long as they are signed in, right?

Comment: Suppose you are opening multiple pages. if you signout on a signle page, this will trigger a redirection to login page in realtime like modern big site (ex: facebook). on traditional website you have to do a refresh on other pages to discover that you are no longer authenticated. same behavior if you delete session cookie. so it provides better user interaction and experience for your website.

Comment: Thanks! -- So then, the follow up question, of course -- is it possible to _not_ have it reactive?  If i am more worried about preventing the app downloading to an unauthorized user -- or just more easily accessing profile information that may not change often?

Comment: Meteor.userId() get the current user id if there is a user logged in, or null if no user is logged in. other then that it will not change. and even if user is logged in, react component can render before Meteor.userId() can get the user id and at first it will contain undefined. so you have to use a package like: (https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) to re-render react components after meteor data is available.